# How to style programmatically an AreaChart series with JavaFX

Tags: css, dynamic, charts, javafx, stacked-area-chart

I am trying in this code to style dynamically my `AreaChart` series but it's not working. I want to change each series background without passing by CSS.

```
XYChart.Series series1 = new XYChart.Series();
series1.getNode().setStyle("chart-series-area-fill { -fx-fill: transparent; }");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Solution*

Use the following code *after you have shown the chart on a stage*:

```
// look up first series fill.
Node node = ac.lookup(".default-color0.chart-series-area-fill");
// set the first series fill to translucent pale green
node.setStyle("-fx-fill: rgba(152, 251, 152, 0.5);");
```

*Why your approach does not work*

You can't apply a css selector in a [setStyle](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/Node.html#setStyle%28java.lang.String%29) call, according to the javadoc:

> this variable contains style properties and values and not the selector portion of a style rule.